# 404 page not found when a url is hit but properly served when opened from the link on index page

Tags: nginx, ember.js, lua

I am using `nginx-lua` module with `redis` to serve static files of `ember-app`. The `index` file content is stored in `redis` as a `value` which is being properly served by `nginx` when the (root) `domain/IP` is hit.

If `login` page is open from link, it gets opened properly. But when opened directly by hitting the url bar or refreshing the page the nginx gives `404 not found`. 
The `index` file is in `redis` and rest of the files are being served from compiled `js` which is present on a `CDN`.
Following is the nginx configuration

```
server
{
  listen 80 ;
  server_name 52.74.57.154;

  root /;

 default_type   text/html;
 location = / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
    set_unescape_uri $key $arg_index_key;
    set $fullkey 'ember-deploy-cli:index:${key}';

     content_by_lua '
                local redis = require "resty.redis"
                local red = redis:new()

                red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 sec



                local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
                if not ok then
                    ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err)
                    return
                end


        if ngx.var.key == "" then
            --ngx.say("No Argument passed")
            local res, err = red:get("ember-deploy-cli:index:current-content")
            ngx.say(res)
            return
        end
        local res, err = red:get(ngx.var.fullkey)

        if res == ngx.null then
            ngx.say("Key doesnt exist ")
            return
        end
        ngx.say(res)

     ';
 }
```

Comment: Does one use post and the other get, while the server only responds to one?

Comment: @randy Nope, these are GET requests only. Like `mydomain/login` when opened through a link from `index` page, it get served properly. But when opened by hitting the url bar or refreshing the page, it shows `404 page not found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following nginx location block has to be added in order to serve the subroutes from index file being served from redis. A detailed explanation and full nginx config can be found [here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/06/ember-cli-deploy-lightning-pack-nginx.html).

```
  # This block handles the subrequest. If any subroutes are requested than this rewrite the url to root and tries to render the subroute page by passing the subroute to index file (which is served by the redis).
  location ~* / {
  rewrite ^ / last;
  }
```